# inserting a value into an object and returning the value

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying provide a function (wrap) that inserts a value into an object in JS and return that value. So if wrap('mystring') is called, 'mystring' should be returned. If wrap(345) is called, 345 (I believe as an integer) should be called and so on and so forth (don't think I need to return an array).

I just want to put the value inside of an object and then to return that value. So the object should be {key: 10} or {key: 'Mine'} and just return the value itself (so return 10 as an integer or return 'Mine" as a string ).

This is my code:

```
function wrap(value) {
  let obj = {}
  const key = value;
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj
}
```

```
Test Passed: Value == 'object';
Expected: 'MyTest', instead got: undefined;
Expected: 343, instead got: undefined;
Expected: { test: 'testy' }, instead got: undefined;
```

These are the tests, and three of the tests are not passed.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you

Comment: What is expected result and what is returning now? please be crispy

Comment: You had a comment on @Bryan Tiwa's answer where you asked a more specific question, which I assume is what you were trying to ask in your question. You should edit this question to ensure you have a very specific question instead of stating a problem and briefly mentioning a currently confusing request.

Comment: Thanks for the inquiry. wrap('hello world') should return 'hello world'. wrap(500) should return 500 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function works i have this

```
function wrap(value) {
  let obj = {}
  // const key = value;
  // obj[key] = value;
  obj['key'] value;
  return obj
}
```

```
console.log(wrap(10)) 
// returns {key: 10} 
console.log(wrap('Mine') 
// returns {key: 'Mine'}
```

It this clearly what you want to do ? Just define the function doesn't execute it.

Comment: Hi Brayan, Thank you for your quick response.  In this case, I just want to put the value inside of an object and then to return that value. So the object should be  {key: 10} or {key: 'Mine'} and just return the value itself (so return 10 as an integer or return 'Mine" as a string )... it's a challenge problem from one of those code challenge sites (not sure if I'm even allowed to say it on here) and I can't seem to figure this out to pass all the tests.

Comment: Remove `const key = value;
  obj[key] = value;`  and write `obj['key'] = value` it will returns `{key: 'Mine'}` for example

Comment: Instead of adding a comment that responds to the OP's comment, you should edit your original answer to make sure that it completely answers OP's question.

Comment: The pleasure was mine.